# PAR::Packer: How to show unpack notification to user?

Tags: windows, perl

I use pp.bat to build executables from Perl scripts. Some executables are several megs in size, so when they are invoked for the first time, it takes few minutes to unpack.

Is there any way to display a notification to a user when such executable is invoked for the first time (to inform user that he has to wait a little)?

Answer (score 2):

[How do I use Win32::GUI::SplashScreen with PAR?](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PAR/lib/PAR/FAQ.pod#How_do_I_use_Win32%3a%3aGUI%3a%3aSplashScreen_with_PAR?)